# How to select data for @Html.DropDownListFor (selectpicker class) when @Html.DropDownList is updated, by jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing web application by ASP.NET-MVC.

Model:

```
public partial class MyModel
{
    public string TEST { get; set; }
}
```

Html:

```
@model IList<MyModel>
@Html.DropDownList("dropDownListSelectToAnotherDropDownList", (SelectList)ViewBag.testList[0], null, new { id = "dropDownListSelectToAnotherDropDownList", title = "[--Select to all--]", @class = "selectpicker form-control", data_style = "btn btn-default", data_width = "100%", data_live_search = "true", data_size = "9" })
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].TEST, (SelectList)ViewBag.testList[i], null, new { id = "dropDownListTest" + i, title = "[--Select Test--]", @class = "selectpicker form-control", data_style = "btn btn-default", data_width = "100%", data_live_search = "true", data_size = "9" })

}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#dropDownListSelectToAnotherDropDownList').on('keyup change', function () {
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        $('dropDownListTest' + i).val($(this).val());
        //$('dropDownListTest' + i).selectpicker('val', $(this).val());
    }
});
```

As the code above, I will get **dropDownListSelectToAnotherDropDownList** and many **dropDownListTest** (For example: dropDownListTest0, dropDownListTest1, ..., dropDownListTestN) that depends on count of model.
I want to create event when **dropDownListSelectToAnotherDropDownList** is change. The event will get data from **dropDownListSelectToAnotherDropDownList** and then set to all **dropDownListTest**. But it's not work.
Could someone help to suggested me, please?

Comment: Are you want to create cascading `DropDownList`? This fiddle from Stephen may be a good start: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym.

Comment: `@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)` is razor code and is executed on the server before its sent to the view. Get rid of those `id` attributes and use a class name for the selector = `var selected = $(this).val(); $.each('.selectpicker', function() { $(this).val(selected); });`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, yes and I already created the dropdown. I want to create event when dropdown is change by jquery. The event will get data from the dropdown and then set to another dropdown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, understand and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should remove all `id` definitions and use separate class name for `<select>` elements created by `DropDownListFor` inside the loop, e.g. `dropDownListTest`:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].TEST, (SelectList)ViewBag.testList[i], null, new { title = "[--Select Test--]", 
                          @class = "selectpicker form-control dropDownListTest", ... })
}
```

Then, use [`jQuery.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to populate them with selected value from `<select>` element with `id="dropDownListSelectToAnotherDropDownList"`. Both examples below should have the same result:

```
// example 1
$('#dropDownListSelectToAnotherDropDownList').on('keyup change', function () {
    val selectedValue = $(this).val();

    $('.dropDownListTest').each(function () {
        $(this).val(selectedValue);
    })
});

// example 2
$('#dropDownListSelectToAnotherDropDownList').on('keyup change', function () {
    val selectedValue = $(this).val();

    $.each($('.dropDownListTest'), function () {
        $(this).val(selectedValue);
    })
});
```